# Scala - how to get data from IO[HttpResponse] in Hammock?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, hammock

I have a simple methods:

```
def retrieveRepositories(url: String, params: String): IO[HttpResponse] = Hammock.getWithOpts(uri"$url", createOpts).exec[IO]
```

Which is a http client. and `json` decoder:

```
implicit def decodeResponseEntity(response: HttpResponse): Either[CodecException, List[GitRepository]] = Decoder[List[GitRepository]].decode(response.entity)
```

Now I want to call this client like this:

```
def getRepos(organization: String, params: String): F[Either[CodecException, List[GitRepository]]] = for {
    res <- retrieveRepositories(organization, params)
    result <- Sync[F].delay(decodeResponseEntity(res))
  } yield result
```

But, there is a problem with `result <- Sync[F].delay(decodeResponseEntity(res))` line, because I got an error: `Type mismatch. Reguired: IO[B_] but found F[Either[CodecException, List[GitRepository]]]`. When I add `unsafeRunSync()` method to `retrieveRepositories(organization, params)` then it works ok, but I should call this method in the end and not here. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you may want to change the definition of `retrieveRepositories` and parameterize on the effect type (`F`) instead of using the concrete `IO` type.

If you can't change `retrieveRepositories`, add a implicit `LiftIO` constraint in `getRepos`. You will be able to use `liftIO` method to lift concrete `IO` values into `F`. An alternative would be use the `Async` typeclass, which inherits from both `Sync` and `LiftIO`.

See documentation for `liftIO`: https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/liftio.html